# Which is correct: "special thanks go to" or "special thanks goes to"?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

what is grammatically correct:

1. Special thanks **go** to Tom...
2. Special thanks **goes** to Tom...

IMHO I'd say *thanks* is one of those plural nouns which implies it requires **go** but I'm not sure.

It's for the acknowledgements section of my thesis; it should be formal English.

Comment: Are they any cases where a plural noun is used with a singular verb (if we take off cases like "the news is good")?

Comment: The protected status is especially fitting for this post, so that no more "thanks!" can occur ;-)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

While neither version sounds incorrect, I would agree that "go" sounds better when no article is used: "special thanks ***go*** to Tom."

If an indefinite article were used, "goes" would be correct: "a special 'thanks' ***goes*** to Tom."

Answer (score 22):

I recommend sidestepping the issue by avoiding the "go" entirely:

> Special thanks to Tom ...
>
> With special thanks to Tom ...
>
> I'd like to give special thanks to Tom ...

Answer (score 18):

The phrase I would expect is *thanks go to*, but looking at the *Corpus of Contemporary American*, I notice that *thanks goes* is also used.

[image: CoCa chart]

Comment: From the chart, I get in Fiction they don't thank anybody. Does that mean nobody thanks in Fiction because they do it for real?

Comment: I like the graph. Given it's for my MSc thesis acknowledgements section, the academic bar convinces me :). Thx!

Answer (score 7):

Actually, either of those examples could be considered grammatical, and neither sounds wrong to my ear.

Formally speaking, it should be *thanks go*, since *thanks* is a plural noun. If in doubt, just use *thanks go* and don't worry about it.

However, because *thanks* is so often used as a fixed expression, more and more people treat it as grammatically singular despite its plural form. For that reason, it's not uncommon to hear *thanks goes*, and this usage sounds natural to me.

Interestingly Google shows [1.9 million results for "thanks go"](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22thanks+go%22) and [3.5 million results for "thanks goes"](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22thanks+goes%22), suggesting that the latter is actually more common. (But the first result for each page is actually a link to this very question in a different forum.) Salt this result liberally with the standard caveats about Google result counts being inaccurate, though.

Comment: As @kiamlaluno said in a comment above, *news* is another example of a formally plural word that is treated as grammatically singular.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Actually I did perform a Google search looking for the according results count..that lead to my doubts and made me post here :).

Answer (score 0):

"A special thank you goes to..."

"Special thanks go to..."

"Thanks" is plural.

"Special thanks goes to" sounds plain wrong to me.  Perhaps it's because I'm Australian.

Answer (score -2):

It will be "special thanks goes to" when it's a singular noun or a group. In plural, it will be "go".