# Is ''thanks'' singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Special thanks go to” or “Special thanks goes to”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15429/special-thanks-go-to-or-special-thanks-goes-to)

I heard a lot of time the following two sentences.

> Many thanks also goes to xyz and abc for [...].
>   Many thanks also go to xyz and abc for [...].

Which one of these two sentences is correct? Is *thanks* singular or plural?

Comment: This is pretty much a dpulicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15429/special-thanks-go-to-or-special-thanks-goes-to — there are some excellent answers there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the sentence you wrote, *many thanks* is plural, and you should write *many thanks go*.

*Thanks* is also used as singular, as shown in the following sentences reported by the *Corpus of Contemporary American English*, which find 13 sentences containing *thanks goes* used in academic context.

> My deepest thanks goes to the German and US journalists who shared their expertise with me in the context of my fieldwork. [ACAD]
>   A special thanks goes to Kara Goodson and Jimmie King at PSA Headquarters. [ACAD]
>   Special thanks goes to the world's exhibitor community for they submitted nearly 2,500 entries (10,000 images) for the judges and ultimately for exhibitions at the Conference in Baltimore. [ACAD]
>   [...] and a lot of thanks goes to Cory Parker. [NEWS]
>   A heartfelt thanks goes out to the staff of the Victims Witness Assistance Program. [NEWS]
>   My heartfelt thanks goes to the police and paramedics for their quick and caring response. [NEWS]

Comment: The part between brackets after the sentence reports in which context the sentence is found.

Comment: I must admit I find "thanks" as a singular sounds odd, even in the examples you quoted.

Comment: To say it all, the _CoCA_ finds 89 sentences containing _thanks go_, and 21 sentences containing _thanks goes_. Using _thanks_ as singular sounds like using _news_ as plural, to me. It doesn't sound so odd to my hears, though.

Comment: In a few of these it seems like maybe the speaker is really saying, *A heartfelt “thanks” goes out to...*. It doesn't sound all that strange to me if I think of it that way.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks is plural, as indicated by the word **many**.

As a result, the use of **goes** here is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

It is both the singular and plural form of the word, like "deer" or "fish".