# Why can't "thanks" ever be singular as a noun?

Tags: etymology, nouns, history, historical-change

While looking at the part of speech of the noun "thanks" in an online dictionary I noticed that it was a plural noun and wondered if it could be used in singular form. Glancing at the origin it appears that the old English word "thanc" was once used as the singular form of this noun. I assume it would be appropriate at that time period to say "I have a thank!" if you felt thankful for a single thing instead of being limited to always say "I have thanks!" as we do in modern English.

Nowadays, I believe we only use the plural form "thanks" as the noun in all cases. We can never have a single "thank". Instead we can only have "thanks"! I find this odd! It would make sense to have kept the singular form of the noun. Often we are grateful for a single action or event and it seems more accurate to have a single "thank" rather than many "thanks".

Is there any known specific background history as to why this is?

Comment: You don't *have* thanks, you *give* them. And it would seem pretty miserly to dole them out one at a time, don't you think?

Comment: I don't think you want 1 half of a pair of pants.

Comment: From my experience, you can have thanks and you can give thanks. I have often heard "feeling thankful" termed as "having thanks." I don't think that it would be miserly to give out a single "thank" if you only had a single "thank" to give. If you had multiple thanks of course why not "give thanks" like we today!

Comment: @Mitch: That was good enough for Long John Silver.

Comment: @slyfin: I don't know where you're from, but I have *never* heard someone say "have thanks."

Comment: related: 1. [Is ''thanks'' singular or plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19790/is-thanks-singular-or-plural); 2. [What does the “s” in “thanks” mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43285/what-does-the-s-in-thanks-mean) and 3. [Is thanks a countable noun? Many thanks or much thanks?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60497/is-thanks-a-countable-noun-many-thanks-or-much-thanks)

Comment: @Robusto [let us have thanks](https://books.google.it/books?id=2qpjIba599QC&pg=PA244&lpg=PA244&dq=let+us+%22have+thanks%22&source=bl&ots=4qcFs-JvVO&sig=g1tVhR7fyq3WYnHTqx_i__-TU9M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vGsxVYaxIYWNsAG2zYPQBg&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=let%20us%20%22have%20thanks%22&f=false)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Never heard that. People don't talk like the bible where I come from.

Comment: I suspect it mainly because "thanks" are free, and you'd have to be a really miserly person to only give one.  (Though, come to think of it, the term in Norwegian is "tak" -- singular.  But I suppose Norwegians are by nature rather frugal.)

Comment: @HotLicks The Norwegian word isn’t really _singular_ as such, in the same way that the English isn’t really _plural_ as such: it’s basically just uncountable. It’s never used in the plural form, but it’s also very rarely used in the definite. (Note: “many thanks” is quite odd in Scandiwegian, since it uses _mange_ [a plural determiner ‘many’] with _tak(k)_, which is singular. The word is sort of numerus-free, rather than singular or plural.)

Comment: Because if it’s singular it’s ***a thank you***: e.g.  *I’d like to give a thank you to my father ...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Thanks* is considered a plural noun, however used to denote one expression of gratitude. There is a transition in the history from the obsolete singular form to the current plural form.

In *OED*, the latest examples of the singular form is from the end of the thirteenth century and the earliest examples of the plural form is from the beginning of fourteenth century.

The latest example of the singular form is from the *Haveloc the Dane*, the second oldest surviving romance written in English. (1300, composition date):

> Þus wolde þe theues me haue reft, But **godþank**, he hauenet sure keft.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>†**Gode þank, God-thank**  [= Latin *Deo gratias*, French *grâce à Dieu*] , thanks (be) to God, thank God.</sub>

There are also earlier usages like:

- Is this the **thanke** which you returne to God? (1642, D. Rogers, *Naaman*)
- He will thank you woman. *M. M.* I will none of his **thanke**. (a1556, N. Udall, *Ralph Roister Doister*)

The earliest example of the plural form is from the *Ayenbite of Inwyt* (a confessional prose work written in a Kentish dialect of Middle English,  translation of the French *Somme le Roi*, 1340):

> Me..him ne yeldeþ **þonkes** of his guodes, þet he ous heþ ydo.

*OED* also mentions that it was formerly sometimes construed as singular and we see an example from 1481, *The History of Reynard the Fox* (William Caxton's English translation):

> All hath he but lytyl **thanke**.

According to OED, the current plural noun form first appears in Shakespeare's *Titus Andronicus* in 1594:

> **Thanks** to men Of Noble minds, is honourable meede.

Another plural form appears in Shakespeare's *Romeo & Juliet* in 1599:

> Else is his **thankes** too much.

Shakespeare might have an influence on the usage of the current plural form and the expression might have been used in that form till today. (there was a slightly different form *thankes* also as mentioned before).

On the other hand, there is also the usage ***a thank*** where *thank* is used in singular noun form. *OED* mentions that it is rare but not obsolete. It might be used mainly in literature and there is an example as late as 1849, from H. W. Longfellow's *Black Knight*:

> The children drank, Gave many a courteous thank.

Finally, *OED* puts the following note below the obsolete sense of *thank* "Kindly thought or feeling entertained towards any one for favour or services received; grateful thought, gratitude. Rarely in *pl.*"):

> The sense of ‘gratitude, kindly or loving feeling for favour or benefit’ must have been developed between that of ‘good will, good feeling’ generally, and that of ‘the expression of gratitude’. But the feeling passes so naturally into its expression that it is not easy to separate them in the quotations, except by the accompanying verbs: *to express one's thanks*, and the archaic *to con thanks*, ought to mean to express one's *feelings of gratitude*; but to *give, offer, return* or *receive thanks*, ought to mean to give or receive *the expression of gratitude*; so *to have thanks*, but this is less clear. In many instances it is impossible to say which is meant...

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your research! This was just what I was looking for, the history of the evolution of the modern "thanks"!

Comment: @slyfin didn't you mean "thanks you" ?

Answer (score 7):

The simple answer to the OP is that it's a *[fixed expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_expression)* because we've said *[thanks](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=thanks&searchmode=none)* that way for many centuries:

> Old English *þanc*, *þonc* in late use "grateful thought, gratitude,"
>   plural form *thanks* from mid-13c., from the same root as [***thank***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=thank) (v.).
>   Compare Old Saxon *thank*, Old Frisian *thank*, Old Norse *þökk*, Dutch
>   *dank*, German *Dank*.
>   The Old English noun originally and chiefly meant
>   "thought, reflection, sentiment; mind, will, purpose;" also "grace,
>   mercy, pardon; pleasure, satisfaction."
>
> As short for *‘I give you thanks’* from 1580s; often with extensions, such
>   as *‘thanks a lot’* (1908). Spelling *thanx* attested by 1907.
>   *emphasis* mine

In the etymology of the verb *[thank](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=thank&allowed_in_frame=0)* we notice a relationship to **think**:

> Old English *þancian*, *þoncian* "to give thanks, thank, to recompense,
>   reward," from Proto-Germanic *thankojan
>   (cognates: Old Saxon
>   *thancon*, Old Norse *þakka*, Danish *takke*, Old Frisian *thankia*, Old High
>   German *danchon*, Middle Dutch, Dutch, German *danken* "to thank"),
>   from
>   *thankoz "thought, gratitude," from PIE root *tong- "to think, feel."
>
> Related phonetically to ***think*** as *song* is to *sing*; for sense evolution,
>   compare Old High German *minna* "loving memory," originally "memory."
>   Related to Old English noun *þanc*, *þonc*, originally "thought," but by
>   c. 1000 "good thoughts, gratitude."
>   In ironical use, "to blame,"
>   from 1550s. *‘To thank (someone) for nothing’* is recorded from 1703.
>   ***emphasis*** mine

It is safe to assume that gratitude produces an **ongoing series of thankful thoughts** as benefits resurface over time. Looking back, *thanks* acknowledges many grateful thoughts. Looking forward, it foresees many grateful thoughts.

After almost 45 years, I haven't forgotten the kindness Mr. Shellinger, my sixth grade teacher, showed me. I have enjoyed many thankful thoughts of him over that time, and I don't suspect them to cease:

> Thanks Mr. S!

Comment: Thanks for the format upgrades, @Mari-Lou A. It really does help to add that emphasis