# What does the "s" in "thanks" mean?

Tags: etymology, grammatical-number

I'm teaching English in a non-English-speaking country where plural "s" and third-person "s" get confused a lot with no "s" at all. The dialogue in the textbook was explaining how you should respond when someone compliments you:

> Mike: For example, when you have a new bag, I can say, "I like your bag." 
>   Yuki: What should I say then? 
>   Mike: You should say, "Thanks." 
>   Yuki: Should I say anything else? 
>   Mike: No. Just "Thanks."

I was asked what the "s" in "Thanks" means, but I couldn't give a straight answer. I know in the phrase "give thanks" it's a plural noun, but what about when it's used as an interjection? Why does it go from "Thank you" to "Thanks"?

Comment: Related: _[Which is correct: “special thanks go to” or “special thanks goes to”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/15429/5822)_

Comment: Note that it is possible to say "thanks you" when there is a third-person subject, as in "the hotel management thanks you for not smoking in the lobby."

Answer (score 29):

You're right that "thanks" is always used as a plural noun, whereas when we say "thank you," the word "thank" is a verb.

You can explain that some nouns are always used in their plural form, and give other examples (clothes, outskirts, glasses, scissors, etc.).

You could alternatively tell your students each expression of thanks is a shortened form of a longer sentence that isn't really in use anymore.

(I) thank you. -- Thank you.

Thanks (be to you).  -- Thanks.

or

(I give/feel) thanks. -- Thanks.

Comment: +1: If you said "I'd like to give you a thank," that would be perceived as extremely stingy.

Comment: @Peter, I'd give your comment +2, but it is only worth one thank.

Answer (score 18):

My interpretation is that *my* is elided.

> [My] thanks!

A longer interpretation would be:

> [I give you my] thanks!

You could also say that it's imperative:

> [Take/receive my] thanks!

*Thanks* is one of many responses we use when time is short or a longer expression seems egregious or pretentious. In a similar vein, we respond to good news with *congratulations!* an unintended slight with *apologies!* or sad news with *condolences.*

Answer (score 9):

It is a plural.

You could say 'Many thanks'

The confusion is that it is not really used as a single noun.

Comment: Do you some evidence which proves this? Because the other ideas in other answers also seem plausible.

Comment: The other ideas in the other answers are also using thanks as a plural noun; they just don't use the word "many".  "My thanks" -> plural noun.  "Thanks be to you" -> plural noun.

Answer (score 1):

*Thanks* should have the same logic as *Gracias* in Spanish or *Grazie* in Italian, all of them are plural nouns. When we say *Gracias* in Spanish we mean *Yo te doy gracias*, i.e., *I give you thanks*.